# Proof of the analyticity of complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

> Let $a\in(-\pi,\pi]$  and $f:G\to\mathbb C$,  $G = \{ z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\},\operatorname{Arg}z\neq a \}$
>   $$f(z)=\ln|z|+\imath \arg_a z,\quad a<\arg_az<a+2\pi$$
>   Prove that $f$ is analytic and that $f'(z)= 1/z$

#### Attempt

I am trying to use a theorem which dictates that if $L(z)-f(z)= 2k\pi$ for $k=1,2,\dots$, then $f(z)$ is a branch and therefore it is analytic, but I have a hard time with $\arg_a(z)$ and its relation to $\operatorname{Arg} z$.

If anyone could help me with this exercise , I would be grateful.
Please excuse my English.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Please consider adding to your question what you have tried and your ideas! That way we can help you as best we can.

Comment: thank you! I am trying to use a theorem which dictates that if L(z)-f(z)= 2kpi k=1,2.. then f(z) is a branch and therefore it is analytic, but I  have a hard time with arg_a(z) and its relation to Argz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity let $Arg(z):=\theta $  then
we have $arg_a z = \theta $ if $\pi \geq \theta >a $  and  $arg_a z= \theta + 2\pi $ otherwise.
So if $\theta \neq \pi $ we have an open nhd. of $z$ with $f(z)-L(z)=$some constant hence 
$f'(z)=L'(z)=1/z$.

For $\theta=\pi$ , you may use Cauchy-Riemann polar equations or inverse function theorem..

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I would upvote your answer, but i lack the required reputation.